# How to put icons into a Kendo Menu?

Tags: css, icons, kendo-menu

I have the following Kendo Menu:

```
<div id="menu"></div>

<script>
    console.log("executes")
    $("#menu").kendoMenu({
        dataSource: [{
            text: "menu", icon: "k-icon k-i-more-horizontal", items: [
                { text: "Edit", spriteCssClass: "k-icon k-i-edit" },
                { text: "Delete", spriteCssClass: "k-icon k-i-delete" },
            ]
        }

        ]
    });
</script>
```

Since `spriteCssClass` is *not recommended* [https://www.telerik.com/forums/spritecssclass-is-not-working-with-icons-in-latest-version] , I tried `icon:...` as you can see in the first line of the dataSource. But that does not work, too.

How can I put Kendo some icons into a Kendo Menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it simply putting a **< span >** into `text` and setting `encoded: false`.

```
   $("#menu").kendoMenu({
        dataSource: [{
            text: "<span class=\"k-icon k-i-more-horizontal\"></span>", encoded: false, items: [
                { text: "<span class=\"k-icon k-i-edit\"></span><span>Edit</span>", encoded: false },
                { text: "<span class=\"k-icon k-i-delete\"></span><span>Delete</span>", encoded: false }
            ]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FontAwesome icons in the Kendo UI Menu as explained in the following article:

- https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/menu/how-to/using-fontawesome-icons#use-fontawesome-icons

Comment: Unfortunately, the docs are outdated - I wrote that spriteCssClass is not supported anymore in my question, 
But referring to my own answer:  replacing  the k-icon class in the <span> -Tag with a fontawesome class would work.

Comment: In order to use the spriteCssClass field, you have to set the styles for the k-sprite class explicitly. Check out the sample project here: https://dojo.telerik.com/aDOTUvet It is using the latest Kendo UI version - 2018.3.1017

Comment: I tried it with the styles for the k-sprite class and it did not work. Maybe I did sth wrong elsewhere.